# Show updated Data after edit on page Reload/Refresh in MVC app

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

So i have a div which can be edited and deleted, now i want to somehow show the updated data after editing or deleting on page after reload/refresh. Is there any way i can accomplish it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have to call the method using $.post and get the updated result.
if its static then you can store in the TempData or viewbag 
else you can store the data in the database and get that when click on the Done(After editing the records).

Also, when the page is refresh or gets loaded, you have to bind the records either from the TempData/ViewBag or from the database.

Do the same for Delete as well.

Enjoy Coding!!!!!